# Trying to find a sci-fi book about a girl living in a tower post nuclear fallout

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

The tower was large enough to hold a **city/states** worth of people. Had water purification, farms, etc. for **sustainability**. I remember she used the equipment to scale the outside of the tower at one point and I feel like she went through the vents at one point. Can anyone help? Would’ve been probably a **teen book** and was read between 2010-2017

Comment: Does the protagonist live inside the tower or on the outside?

Comment: Sounds a bit like the WOOL stories by Hugh Howey

Comment: It reminds me of "Floor 21" by Jason Luthor, but I don't think she scaled the outside of the tower (there was a lot of crawling through vents though).

Answer (score 6):

Just possibly [The Girl Who Dared to Think](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35609598-the-girl-who-dared-to-think) by Bella Forrest.

[image: The Girl Who Dared to Think]

It is set in a tower in a post nuclear landscape, and there are farms and water treatment facilities as you say. The protagonist Liana Castell does have to climb the outside of the tower as part of her work as a maintenance engineer.

I don't recall Liana climbing through the ventilation system, but there vents that deliver a toxic gas to ... erm ... "deal" with what the authorities regard as social undesirables.

However this was published in 2017 so it's right at the end of your time range.

This is the first in [a series of seven books](https://www.goodreads.com/series/213736-the-girl-who-dared).